# Adding a Doctype to the document dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, doctype

I want to detect whether a doctype exists for the current document and add one if nothing exists.

I'm able to check whether a doctype exists using `document.doctype`. But how can i add one?

Comment: bad idea. I believe it is read only.

Comment: Oh my. In IE 7 and IE 8 if no doctype is specified it is running in Quirks mode. So position:fixed is not working. Hence i want to add a doctype dynamically.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if it's possible to get the page to change modes once it's loaded.

Comment: is there any other possibility by which i can tell the browser not to run in quirks mode?

Comment: At runtime, the browser would have already made up his mind. So you can't change the render mode during render. Makes sense, yes?

Comment: Yes, makes sense. Now i need to look for a hack to make IE 7 work with position:fixed in quirks mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change the page mode from within the page. Sorry.